# Getting values as a string from multiple checkbox

Tags: angularjs, ionic3

I know this question has been asked and answered multiple times, but I cannot seem figure out how to implement them into my application.  I am pretty new to Ionic and Angular.

I have a dropdown checkbox list where a user can select one or more answers.  I need the values selected to be sent as a string.  When submitting the form, I get this error. This error occurs regardless of if it is one or more answers.

[image]

HTML

```html
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>1. Type of Incident or Observation</ion-label>
      <ion-select multiple="true" formControlName="firstQuestionAnswer" required [(ngModel)]="stopCardRequest.firstQuestionAnswer">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let firstQuestionAnswer of firstQuestionOptions" value="{{firstQuestionAnswer.value}}">{{firstQuestionAnswer.name}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

TS

```js
  firstQuestionOptions = [
    { name: "Near Miss", value: "Near Miss" },
    { name: "First Aid", value: "First Aid" },
    { name: "Medical Beyond First Aid (HSE will conduct investigation)", value: "Medical Beyond First Aid (HSE will conduct investigation)" },
    { name: "Lost Time", value: "Lost Time" },
    { name: "Environmental (spills / releases)" ,value: "Environmental (spills / releases)" },
    { name: "Security", value: "Security" },
    { name: "Vehicle / Equipment Incident", value: "Vehicle / Equipment Incident" },
    { name: "Fire", value: "Fire"  },
    { name: "Illness", value: "Illness" },
    { name: "General Observation", value: "General Observation" }
  ];

  public submitRequest(values) {
    this.showLoading().then(() => {
      this.stopCardProvider.save(this.stopCardRequest).subscribe(
        () => {
          this.logger.info("Stop Card sent");
          this.alertProvider.showSubmission();
          this.stopCardForm.reset();
          // Dismiss loading overlay.
          this.loading.dismiss();
        },
        error => {
          // Dismiss loading overlay.
          this.loading.dismiss();
          this.alertProvider.showError(error);
        });
    });
  }
```

In the model, the firstQuestionAnswer is a string.  I am not sure what else anyone would need to answer this, so please let me know and I will give you what I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your array to string and pass it whenever you can

Here ex:

`this.selectedItem=["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
this.selectedItem=this.selectedItem.toString();`